# During a dialog alexa responses with sessionEnd voice, without any reason

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

this is my use case:

i created a skill which includes a dialog model. This model aks the user for serveral slot values. Every slot value will then be checked if the answer is right or not. When ist right the dialog goes on, if not alexa aks the user again (via elicitslot). So my problem is, wehn i give a wrong answer, alexa ends the session without any reason, she does not fire the elicitslot direction.

The strange thing is, during tests bevor, everything worked finde. And then I just changed something on the interaction model (I added a slot) and then it does not work anymore.

Note: this affects only 4 of 10 slot values. For the other 6 values the elicitslot direction works fine. But for the other 4 not. And the problem is, i can't see anything in the logs. So i dont know why this happens.

The main problem is, in one run everything works and in the next it the elicitslot does not work for 4 slot values.

[image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0UWc.png)
Here you can see it, "ziege" is not the right answer so normaly alexa should aks now "please try again...". But she ends the session, whyy???

[image without error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9fxX.png)
And this is the slot bevor, there everything worked fine. "Schildkröte" is wrong, so alexa asks the user to enter the right value. This is all in the same session...

Are there any bugs which i dont know? Or hase it something to go with the slot types..?

Please its for my thesis, and in really need help.

Note: i work with the amazon lambda editor..

Comment: We get <Audio only response> when the response is not right. Please share your lamda logs. And also the request generated.

Comment: These are the only logs i get in CloudTrail:
"eventTime": "2018-07-28T12:57:24Z",
"eventSource": "monitoring.amazonaws.com",
"eventName": "DescribeAlarms",
"awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
 "sourceIPAddress": "90.186.254.43",
 "userAgent": "signin.amazonaws.com",
 "errorCode": "ValidationException",
 "errorMessage": "1 validation error detected: Value 'INVALID_FOR_SUMMARY' at 'stateValue' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [INSUFFICIENT_DATA, ALARM, OK]",
    "requestParameters": {
        "stateValue": "INVALID_FOR_SUMMARY"

Comment: i get no logs in cloudwatch about that issue. And i have also no request, because alexa ends the session without sending something.

Comment: i think it hase something to do with the slot types. because when i change something there some of my slots are working then. But not all.